What was the coven's plan for Mae and Osha?
The Jedi clearly expect something sinister about what Mae and Osha's mother has in store for them, asking meaningfully why

only Mae has the markings of leadership (does one of them have to die?) or how two young children could possibly become the leaders of the coven (an essence transfer plot?)

However, most of what we have seen suggests genuine care for the girls, and even Mother Aniseya seems willing to let Osha become a Jedi if that is her desire. Still, presumably one does not use the Force to create life just for the fun of it.
What were the plans that Mother Aniseya and the rest of the coven had for Osha and Mae?

Just a technicality, but I dont think they were Nightsisters. I think they were a standalone group.

@knightwatch - Upon further thought, I think it is ambiguous. The Jedi speculate that they are Nightsisters, but then say that Nightsisters do not train younglings (but then, it could be different for the children of the leader, or generally for powerful children created artificially from a vergence in the Force). Against: all the Nightsisters we saw before were from a single species, planet, and culture (or nearly so). In favor: They are an entirely female group of Force users that use the same title (Mother) for their leader and show knowledge of similar Force techniques.

It's a simple and elegant plan: 1. Use a vergence in the Force, whatever the hell that is (possibly a tree?), to create life. 2. Put that life into two bodies. 3. ??? 4. Profit!

@PaulD.Waite - It's just something that converges or diverges, like a nexus of force energy.

only Mae has the markings of leadreship // It is shown in the episode that Mae simply went first and then Osha backed out and the entire process was interrupted by the Jedi.

@ThePopMachine - Right. I only mention that to point out that the Jedi are suspicious that something shady is going on, and suggesting what they got out of that question.
